# Same widget code on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm creating a widget using jQuery. It's a charting widget which communicates with the server (PHP) through ajax to update the chart.

My problem is that I need 2 of this widget on the same page without one overwriting the other.
How can I encapsulate the javascript code without using the same code twice and without defining separate events for each chart control, update button, etc. ?

Comment: it would help us help you if you have code samples...

Answer (score 1):

If you encapsulate your functionality into a class, then instantiate that class into two different variables, you should have all the separation you need.

```
var chart_one = new myChart(x,y,z);
var chart_two = new myChart(a,b,c);

chart_one.display();
chart_two.display();
```

[This page](http://www.phpied.com/3-ways-to-define-a-javascript-class/) contains a good tutorial on javascript classes.

Comment: I'm using the Javascript object notation like this:

var chart = {

    init: function() {
        doStuff();
    }
}